# Why program is giving unexpected output?

Tags: c

I'm stuck in a problem given in a book. The problem is -

> The prototypical Internet newbie is a fellow name B1FF,who has a unique way of wriring messages.Here’s a typical B1FF communique.:
>   H3Y DUD3, C 15 R1LLY C00L
>  
>   Write a “B1FF filter” that reads a message entered by the user and translates it into B1FF-speak:
>      Enter message: Hey dude, C is rilly cool
>     In B1FF-speak : H3Y DUD3, C 15 R1LLY C00L
>   Your program should convert the message to upper-case letters,substitute digits for certain letters (A=4,B=8,E=3,I=1,O=0,S=5).

**My Program-**

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
     {
        char arr[50]={0},ch[50]={0};
        int i=0;
        printf("\nenter the sentence : ");

        while(arr[i-1]!='\n')
        {
         scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
         i++;
        }

       i=0;

       while(arr[i]!='\n')
       {
        if(arr[i]=='e')
        ch[i]='3';
        if(arr[i]==('A'||'a') )
        ch[i]='4';
        if(arr[i]==('B'||'b'))
        ch[i]='8';
        if(arr[i]==('I'||'i'))
        ch[i]='1';
        if(arr[i]==('o'||'O'))
        ch[i]='0';
        if(arr[i]==('S'||'s'))
        ch[i]='5';

       else ch[i]=arr[i]-32;
       i++;

     }

   ch[i]='\n';
   i=0;
   printf("\nIn B1FF-SPEAK : ");

   while(ch[i]!='\n')
   {
    printf("%c",ch[i]);
    i++;
   }

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT OF THE PROGRAM-**
[image]

I don't understand why the program is not converting the alphabets and why `scanf()` is not accepting `space` as a character ?

Comment: Walk thru it with a debugger.  Pay attention to the value of i -- especially on the line where you subtract one from it then use it as an array index!

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` to read single characters? You know, it can read the whole string, right? Also read `man scanf` to understand what it is doing with spaces.

Comment: Properly indent your code so you can see the logical mistakes in your if-statements.

Comment: use getchar() in place of scanf() you don't need formatted input.

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy/paste text is certainly easier than posting a screenshot!

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, you cannot chain the logical OR operator like

```
  if(arr[i]==('A'||'a') )
```

and get what you're *expecting*, because this resolves to an always TRUE condition. [*`('A'||'a')` evaluates to TRUE*]

You have to use

```
  if ( (arr[i]=='A') || (arr[i] =='a'))
```

That said,

- `ch[i]=='8';`, `ch[i]==1;` are basically *empty* statements. You're comparing and discarding the comparison result. If you want assignment, you need to use `=`.
- the `else ch[i]=arr[i]-32;` **only** binds with the previous `if` statement, no the whole `if` *chains*. You can either make use of `switch` case or `if-else if-else` constructs to take care of that part.
- you did not handle whitespaces separately.

---

To elaborate, due to the second point above, you code basically reduces to

```
while(arr[i]!='\n')
   {
    if(arr[i]==('S'||'s'))  //always false
    ch[i]='5';

   else ch[i]=arr[i]-32;   //always TRUE
   i++;
 }
```

which is just a *poor attempt to convert* lowercase to UPPERCASE. In case a non-alpha input is there in the string, the code will blow up.

That said, regarding the

> why `scanf()` is not accepting space as a character?

part, `scanf()` perfectly accepts a *space* as an input with `%c`, it's you just convert it no `NUL` (`null`) by *blindly* subtracting `32` from a `space` which has an [ASCII value of decimal 32](http://www.asciitable.com/). A `NUL` is non printable, and does not appear in the output.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.Although my code was wrong but atleast `e` should be converted to `3`.Why it not get converted ?

Comment: @sourav oops that is written by mistake.I've edited it but again i'm getting the same result.

Comment: @user239887 I explained in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SouravGhosh  why this statement **if(arr[i]==('S'||'s'))**  is always false ?

Comment: @user239887 because, that is essentially the same as `if(arr[i]== 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Some recommendations:

- Don't use lots of little calls to `scanf("%c"...)`.  Use `fgets()` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)).  `fgets` reads in a whole line from input, stores it in your buffer (including the newline), and sticks a '\0' byte at the end of it so you know how long the string is.
- use `toupper()` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper)).  It takes an arbitrary character as input.  If the input is a lower case letter, then the output is the upper-case version of that letter.  Otherwise, the output is the same as the input.
- Update the array in-place.  You don't need two arrays.  Read the array with `fgets()`, loop over it with your translation logic, updating each character as you go, then write the array out with `fputs()`.
- Learn about switch statements.  A switch statement will make your code more compact and easier to read.  You need one case for every letter->number transform, and a default case for everything else.

  ```
  c = toUpper(c);
  switch (c) {
      case 'A': c = '4'; break;
      case 'B': c = '8'; break;
      ....
      default: break;
  }
  ```